# ACF: Not displaying ACF data from another post

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I'm trying to pull data from an ACF module in another post and display it on a page. I've followed (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/) and triple checked that my syntax is correct, afaik, but the post data is not coming through.

This is my markup. I've checked the post ID and it corresponds correctly but testing fields doesn't display the correct information. The result of `<?php echo get_sub_field('module_size', $postID), ' ', get_sub_field('module_margins', $postID),' ', $postID;?>` is `mod_feature-3-3 mod_feature-margin-large 3101`. The first 2 are classes that belong to the current post and not the other post but the ID `3101`is correct.

```
<?php
        $post = get_sub_field('post');
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $author_id = $post->post_author;
        $postID = $post->ID; 
    ?>

    <div class="m16_content">

        <!-- Slideshow -->
        <div class="m16_slides">
        <?php echo get_sub_field('module_size', $postID), ' ', get_sub_field('module_margins', $postID),' ', $postID;?>
            <ul class="rslides_m16 rslides">    
                <?php 
                if( have_rows('items', $postID) ):
                    while ( have_rows('items', $postID) ) : the_row();?>
                        <li>
                            <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image');?>">
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile;
                endif; ?>     
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this code within another loop? get_sub_field is meant to be used within a have_rows loop, and won't work outside it. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out. It's inside of a flexible content module so need an extra loop.

Answer (score 1):

There was a flexible content container with the content inside that required an extra loop to reach the content. This helped (https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-another-pages-flexible-content/)

```
    <ul class="rslides_m16 rslides">    
                <?php 
                if( have_rows('page_modules', $postID) ):
                    while ( have_rows('page_modules', $postID) ) : the_row();

                        if(get_row_layout() == "2-carousel-featured"):

                            if( have_rows('items') ):
                                while ( have_rows('items') ) : the_row();?>

                                <li>
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image');?>">
                                </li>

                                <?php endwhile;
                            endif;

                        endif;  

                    endwhile;
                endif; ?>     
            </ul>
```